# Regex pattern for a String contains "at least one digit and allows only two special chars"

Tags: javascript, java

I have requirement like this for Regex pattern for a string:

```
    1.String length >=8;
    2.Contains at-least one digit.
    3.Contains exactly two special characters in string.
    4.remaining characters are alphabets.
```

I have tried like this:

```
   "/^(?=.*[0-9]+)(?=.*[@#$%]{2})[0-9@#$%A-Za-z]{8,}$/g"
```

But in this examples i am getting:

```
   1."Example1#@"      --true    (passed my test)
   2."Example2#"       --false   (passed my test)
   3."Example3@@##$#"  --true    (failed my test)
```

==>In 3rd case it is accepting more than 2 special characters.

How to achieve my requirement, please help me solve this.

Comment: On the internet, there are regex testers, who are executing regexes piece by piece. You might have a look there and find out what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:\w*[@#$%]){2}(?!\w*[@#$%]))[\d@#$%A-Za-z]{8,}
```

https://regex101.com/r/9iyoIX/2

`(?=\D*\d)` - at least one digit

`(?=(?:\w*[@#$%]){2}(?!\w*[@#$%]))` - Repeat (optional word characters followed by a special character) 2 times, then negative lookahead for more special characters

`(?=[\d@#$%A-Za-z]{8,})` - String is at least 8 characters long, and only contains the desired types of characters

Note that `\d` is preferable to `[0-9]` - easier to read. Also, when you're looking for a certain number of characters of a particular type in a string, a *negated character set* has better performance than `.*`. For example, when looking for a digit, better to use

```
(?=\D*\d)
```

than

```
(?=.*\d)
```

which will be more efficient - the regex will fail quicker when there's no match.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but there is one more bug that your expression passes with out one digit. Our requirement condition 2=> that "contains at-least one digit" will fail.

Comment: The `(?=\D*\d)` ensures that the string contains at least one digit. (The regex101 demo won't be completely accurate because it's checking multiple inputs, not just one)

Comment: We gone through the pattern you have posted, and we changed our requirement A-Z in place of special characters that it means pattern allows only two A-Z chars. ^(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:\w*[A-Z]){2}(?![^A-Z]*[A-Z]))[\d@#$%A-Za-z]{8,} we wrote this  but it didn't work. Please provide link or tutorial for "logical pattern writing" .

Comment: Close, but `\w*[@#$%]` in the original pattern (which checked for the number of special characters) needs to turn into `[^A-Z]*[A-Z]` to check for the number of letters. Can't use `\w` anymore because `\w` includes both letters and numbers. Try `^(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}(?![^A-Z]*[A-Z]))[\d@#$%A-Za-z]{8,}`